# Database design - How should we design a teacher/student relationship when student records themselves also need to be associated to each other

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

So this is something that we've been struggling to try and figure out how to optimize.

---

In a simple world, this might be solved by a simple many-to-many bridging table like this:

- `teachers_students_mappings`

| id | teacher_id | student_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 |

However, we have another complexity here to grapple with. A student record can come from different "sources", i.e.:

1. The student was created by another system transferring the records of that student and their classes to us (most student and teacher-student relationship records are created this way).
2. The student registered on their own (through an app), or
3. The student was manually created by a teacher (via a teacher portal)

We therefore have cases where student records, from different sources, should be related to each other too:

- `students`

| id | name | id_number | source_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Rachel Doe | 9898123 | created_by_system |
| 2 | Rachel Doe | 9898123 | app_user |
| 3 | John Doe | 9833456 | created_by_teacher |

e.g. Above, we have a case where student_ids 1 & 2, Rachel Doe, are actually the same person. The first record was generated automatically by the system, and the 2nd record was created when Rachel registered in the system on her student app. Both records share an `id_number`, which is a unique identifier in the school.

---

If we made it so both student_ids 1 and 2 were linked to all of Rachel's teachers, her teachers would be seeing duplicated records, i.e. both Rachel's app account, and her record created by the system. It seems it might therefore be smarter to relate both these `student_id` records to each other, but how would that impact the `teachers_students_mappings` table?

It is also theoretically possible that 3 unique student records exist for the same student (i.e. the teacher manually created a record, then the system created it, then the student created an account on the app).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database)

Comment: The logic needs `id_number` column to be unique. Create according UNIQUE index, and MySQL will not allow to insert the row with the value which is already present. Your client software must process this duplication error and point the operator to tthe existing row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have an `id_number` that is unique and provides the mechanism to realize that you have *one*, not *two* Rachel Does, use it as the `PRIMARY KEY` of the `Students` table.  Do *not* also have another `id` for each student.

On the other hand, if you have a `StudentHistory` table that records various actions taken by or for each student, it would need its own `PRIMARY KEY`.  This seems to be a separate topic.

So, when "inserting" or "Updating" a row for a student, use

```
INSERT INTO Students (id_number, name, foo, ...)
    VALUES ("9898123", "Rachel Doe", 123, ...)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        foo = VALUES(foo), ...;
```

Or (if coming from a `SELECT`):

```
INSERT INTO Students (id_number, name, foo, ...)
    SELECT id_number, name, foo, ...
        FROM other table ...
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        foo = VALUES(foo), ...;
```

Answer (score -1):

Before entering the data of a new record you have to check if the id_number exists. In that case you have to return the identification and not insert that record.